# Session variable unavailable in ajax handler ( php script )

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-variables

My directory structure looks like below:

```
public_html
    |_ ajax
        |_ test_handler.php
    |_ test.php
```

My test.php looks like this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["tested"]) && $_SESSION["tested"] == "NO"){
    //unset the session array and destroy current session
    destroyActiveSession();

    //start a new session
    session_start();

    $_SESSION["test_var"] = "Hello world!"
    $_SESSION["tested"] = "YES"
}
```

test_handler.php has following code(simplified):

```
session_start();
exit($_SESSION["test_var"]);
```

**Using local environment(XAMPP) and executing on google crome**

In `test.php` page `$_SESSION["test_var"]` works fine but in `test_handler.php` I'm getting `Undefined index: test_var` error. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: If you output `session_id()` in each test.php and test_handler.php, do you get the same session ID?

Comment: You are right @ShaunE.Tobias the session ids are not same. so why??

Comment: It could be a number of reasons. Is this all local? Is the backend at the same domain as the front end? Do you use load balancing? Also, how are you accessing these files? Directly in the browser? From a UI via AJAX?

Comment: I've created a local environment using XAMPP @ShaunE.Tobias

Comment: Okay, are you just going directly to 'test.php' then 'test_handler.php' in the browser? I feel like you may need to share more of what's in those files to help debug

Comment: Going directly to test.php? YES, Is the back end and front end in the same domain? YES. Load balancing? new to me. Accessing the files from a UI via ajax ? YES. Simply running the page on a browser @ShaunE.Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone ran into this problem, here's what solved my problem:
New `test.php`:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["tested"]) && $_SESSION["tested"] == "NO"){

    //unset the session array 
    $_SESSION = array();

    $_SESSION["test_var"] = "Hello world!"
    $_SESSION["tested"] = "YES"
}
```

And new `test_handler.php` :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    exit( $_SESSION["test_var"] );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you need to set the value initially to ensure the logic test operates correctly

```
<?php
    #test.php

    session_start();
    /*
        In the original code the session variable was not set before 
        any form of testing.. set an initial value
    */
    if( !isset( $_SESSION["tested"] ) ) $_SESSION["tested"]='NO';


    if( isset( $_SESSION["tested"] ) && $_SESSION["tested"] == "NO" ){
        destroyActiveSession();

        session_start();

        $_SESSION["test_var"] = "Hello world!"
        $_SESSION["tested"] = "YES"
    }
?>
```

and it makes sense to test when trying to output the value late via ajax

```
<?php
    #test_handler.php
    session_start();
    $var=isset( $_SESSION["test_var"] ) ? $_SESSION["test_var"] : 'bogus';
    exit( $var );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "If" condition appears to be wrong in: $_SESSION["tested"] = "NO"

Try:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["tested"]) && $_SESSION["tested"] == "NO"){
    //unset the session array and destroy current session
    destroyActiveSession();

    //start a new session
    session_start();

    $_SESSION["test_var"] = "Hello world!"
    $_SESSION["tested"] = "YES"
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo. But still my question is the same??